# jquery callback validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation, codeigniter

Is there a way to perform a callback function with jquery's validation plugin that can look for the function in a different controller?

Meaning I have my register controller however I want it to look inside my users model that houses EVERYTHING user related and perform the is_username_available function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your validation function is just called `is_username_available`, you will need to create a decorator for this method, and allow it to be called publicly from your controller.

```
function validation_username_available($username)
{
    if ($this->is_username_available($username))
        die("true");
    die("false");
}
```

Then you make an AJAX call to `/register/validation_username_available/Bob` and read the output, either `true` or `false`.

Also, your validation function `is_username_available` should really be prefixed with an underscore, like `_is_username_available`. Otherwise it can be accessed publicly through `/register/is_username_available/Bob`. That is probably something you don't want.

Comment: Okay now here's another question. I can't find it on the validation plugin for jquery docs but how do I do the callback for this function inside of the rules. I remember its like callback_something but not sure what or how to do it.

Comment: `callback_is_username_available`. If you have done as I suggested and renamed `is_username_available` to `_is_username_available`, you have to include two underscores. `callback__is_username_available`.